# Calling a function depending on a uitableview cell value

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

Please help.

**I have this `tableview`.**  If a cell is clicked, the function would depend on what is the string value of the cell. It has to be like this:

```
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (cell is equal to "Dog") 
    [show puppies]
    else if (cell is equal to "Cat")
    [show puppies]
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Off the top of my head:

Using a default UITableViewCell

```
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{      
        NSString *currentString = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].textLabel.text;

        if ([currentString isEqualToString:@"Dog"]){
            [show puppies]
        }else  if ([currentString isEqualToString:@"Cat"]){
            [show kittens]
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call the same function and pass the string to it inside the function try using switch if you have fixed cases

```
// your method

-(void)showAnimal:(NSString*)animal
{
//here goes your conditional code
}
```

use any conditional structure which you think will be optimized.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     UITableViewCell *cell = [self tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    if ([cell.textLabel.text isEqualToString: @"Dog"]) 
        [self showPuppies];
    else if ([cell.textLabel.text isEqualToString: @"Cat"])
        [self showKittens];
}

-(void)showPuppies
{
  // Your code here
}

-(void)showKittens
{
  // Your code here
}
```